# Get secret variable from Azure Key Vault to remote agent in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-secrets

I'm creating a pipeline deploying an environment on premise. For the I have an on-prem agent where the pipeline is running. It has no access to the Azure Key Vault. At the same time I want to use in my pipeline credentials stored in Azure Key Vault.

I created a variable group and linked to Azure Key Vault and added secret I need. Then I referred the variable group in my pipeline and used the variable like this:

```
- variables:
  - group: MyGroup

- jobs:
  - job: OnPrem
    pool: onprem
    steps:
      - bash: dologin -u user -p $(mySecret)
```

At the moment of executing the bash step pipeline times out because the agent has no network connection to Azure.

```
Starting: Download secrets: azure-secrets
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure Key Vault
Description  : Download Azure Key Vault secrets
Version      : 1.232.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault
==============================================================================
SubscriptionId: xxx.
Key vault name: azure-secrets.
Downloading secret value for: mySecret.
##[error]
mySecret: "connect ECONNREFUSED xxxx:443"
Finishing: Download secrets: azure-secrets
```

The question is - how do I bring it to the job, that is executed on that agent?

I tried to do:

- separate job executed on the agent from variable obtaining
- using macro variable and assigning to another variable so it would be passed to the job as a value

Comment: If your agent doesn't have network access to your keyvault, you can't get values from the keyvault at runtime. It's just that simple.

Comment: As the agent has no network connection to Azure, it is impossible to get the azure key Vault.

Comment: Can the Key Vault be accessed at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the following resources,

1. Azure pipleine
2. Azure Key vault
3. Service principal.
4. Service connection
   you can use this microsoft document to create the above resources([Query azure key vault from azure pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/key-vault-in-own-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=portal)).

Then you can make use of the AzureKeyVault@2 task to read the keyvault secrets from the pipeline like below,

- task: AzureKeyVault@1

  displayName: 'the name for your '

  inputs:

  ```
    azureSubscription: 'your subscription id'

    KeyVaultName: 'your key vault name'

    SecretsFilter: 'key for the secret you are trying to retrieve'
  ```

*SecretsFilter if you are trying to retrieve specific keys from KayVault.

If you want all the keyvault secrets, remove the **SpecificSecrets** from the inputs.

To use the keyvault secret in your pipeline, you can make use of this syntax:
$(KeyVaultSecretKey). Hope this helps!

Comment: How does this help when the problem is a networking issue?